# How to hide profile2 field label and captcha label in registration form

Tags: users, forms

I've tried using 2 different functions, where both successfully sets the value to 'invisible' with a dsm($form) check. However, the label is still being displayed.

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
          case 'user_register_form':
              $form['profile_users']['field_username']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';
              $form['captcha']['#title_display'] = "invisible";
   break;
  }
}
```

and:

```
function MYMODULE_form_profile2_edit_PROFILETYPE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){

     $form['profile_PROFILETYPE']['field_username']['#title_display'] = 'invisible';

}
```

I do not encounter this problem for the username, password and email fields.

Edit: I've also tried:

```
$form['profile_users']['field_username']['und']['#title'] = '';
$form['profile_users']['field_username']['und']['#title_display'] = "invisible";
```

Comment: Could you ask it in a form of a question, like "how to ... ?"

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code instead:

```
$form['captcha']['#title'] = '';
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: title says "Hide profile2 and captcha label in registration form" so how come my answer doesn't answer the question?

Comment: If you think it is the way, say it. Not ask. It very much looks like a question, not answer.

Comment: $form['captcha']['captcha_widgets']['captcha_response']['#title'] = ''; worked! thanks :)

Comment: I'm still having problems with profile2 though. I managed to locate #title variable the where the label was printed and changed it to '', and it worked by changing the variable but it isn't reflected in the user register form...